# Writing the EL equations in the language of differential geometry

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I want to explore generalised Noether currents obtained from $q$-form symmetries in an action.

The regular way we obtain Noether currents is fairly straightforward: We have a 0-form symmetry $\phi \to \phi + \delta \phi$, and the action $S(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi)\to S(\phi + \delta \phi, \partial_\mu \phi + \partial_\mu \delta \phi) \approx S(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi) + \partial_\mu j^\mu$ where $j^\mu$ is the Noether current.

I want to perform this calculation for $q$-form symmetries, or even just 1-form symmetries. It should result in a $d-q-1$ form (Or equivalently $q+1$ form) current. The key steps in my opinion are to understand how to write down the Euler Lagrange equation that results when you vary an action with respect to forms rather than fields.

So it would be something like: $\psi \to \psi + \omega$ where $\psi, \omega \in \Omega^1(M^d)$, and then we should be able to write down $S\to S + \delta S$ where $\delta S$ is a total derivative of a $q$ form?

Any further insight would be very appreciated!